# How can I get my ASP table control to show/hide? (not as simple as it sounds)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Alright, I'm fairly new to ASP.NET, but I think I understand what's going on,. I've been tasked with building reports in them. So far, I've got everything down except for this one issue.

I use a Repeater that's databound to a DataRowCollection and programatically build a table through that. I have something similar to:

```
Private Sub SubAcctGrid_OnItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
        Dim currentrow = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRow)
        Dim acctSummaryTable = New Table With {.ID = "acctSummary" & e.Item.ItemIndex, .CssClass = "minisub_acct_table"}
        Dim drillDownTable = New Table With {.ID = "drillDownTable" & e.Item.ItemIndex, .CssClass = "drilldown_table"}

        ' Build both tables here

        acctSummaryTable.Rows(1).Cells(0).Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("displayDetailTable('{0}')", drillDownTable.ID))
        acctSummaryTable.Rows(1).Cells(1).Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("displayDetailTable('{0}')", drillDownTable.ID))

        e.Item.Controls.Add(acctSummaryTable)
        e.Item.Controls.Add(drillDownTable)

    End If
End Sub
```

I have a Javascript function that takes in the element ID and hides or shows the table:

```
function displayDetailTable(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID)
    if (table.style.display == "none") {
        table.style.display = "table";
    }
    else {
        table.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I can't, for the life of me, pass in the correct element ID, though. From what I understand, ASP.NET transforms the ID I assign into some huge long ID for the sake of uniqueness. For example, I assign a table with the ID 'drillDownTable0' and it spits out 'ctl00_drillDownTable0' in the HTML markup. It worked the first time around, but then the Repeater gets binded to a new row and then I get 'ctl01_drillDownTable0' so on and so forth.

I've tried the ClientID, ID, and UniqueID where I add the attributes to the Cells in the code above and they don't do what I need to.

Is there any way I can get that ID and pass it to the Javascript function? Or I guess a better question is: When are the IDs generated and can I get to them before the page is rendered in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You're probably  looking for  [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx):</strike>

```
String.Format("displayDetailTable('{0}')", drillDownTable.ClientID)
```

Apart from that, i would recommend to create controls dynamically in Repeater's [`ItemCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcreated%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event. You must recreate all dynamical controls on every postback. `ItemDataBound` is only called on databinding whereas `ItemCreated` is called on every postback.

**Edit**: I've only just seen that you've already tried ClientID. But it might be an issue caused by creating the table in ItemdataBound.

Comment: When I output the results of UniqueID, ID, and ClientID to the debug output window, I get "drillDownTable0", which is the ID I assigned to the table instead of the ID that's in the HTML. Note that my Repeater itself is a dynamic control created in Page_Init. Might that have something to do with it?

Comment: @Duracell: Create the table in ItemCreated. If you need to access the DataItem, you can fill the table in ItemDataBound. Use `FindControl("drillDownTable" & e.Item.ItemIndex)` to get a reference to your table. But create it earlier (in the page's life-cycle) in ItemCreated. You must use ClientID anyway. Add your `onclick` event in ItemDataBound(as now).

Comment: @Duracell: You're setting is too complicated and error-prone. Why do you create the tables dynamically at all(and also the repeater)? Couldn't you create them declaratively on aspx?

Comment: My report layout also has a bunch of tables that are displayed in a weird hierarchial sense, and I went with what I knew at the time. I initially did lay it out declaratively in the aspx file, but I knew that Databinder.Eval uses Reflection and that it's rather costly; I'm looking for performance. I also felt that DataGrids and GridViews were a bit too inflexible for what I needed to do. I decided to just go about it a different way. Anyways, that did work by creating the table in the ItemCreated event and adding the onclick event in ItemDataBound. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Duracell: Declaring them declaratively does not mean that you must use `DataBinder.Eval`. You can bind them in codebehind (RowDataBound in GridView, ItemDataBound in Repeater,FormView,ListView,..).